# Trying to parse everything after postion=1 of a record

Tags: mysql

The below code will parse value 2 of found  db records, is there a way to parse everything after 2?

IE: 2-4 or 2-* (basicly whatever is left 2 and so on)

Value 1 is being used for another column.

```
LEFT JOIN ps_image pi2 ON ps_product.id_product=pi2.id_product and pi2.position = 2
```

I have tried 2,3,4 2-4 I can't seem to figure out if their is a wild card or anything close to that.

Comment: Have you tried `position>2`?

Comment: That did it, thanks so much @MEE

Answer (score 1):

Per @MEE position>2 allowed me to grab everything after postion 2 in the lookup